# Cascade Delete doesn't work right when deleting intermediate entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3 entities: Grandpa, Father and Child with the expected relationships 
Grandpa has many Fathers and Fathers has many Children

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Grandpa")
public class Grandpa {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
     @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
     @Column(name = "id")
     private int id;

     @CreationTimestamp
     @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
     @Column(name = "created_at")
     private Date createdAt;

     @UpdateTimestamp
     @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
     @Column(name = "updated_at")
     private Date updatedAt;

     @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "grandpa")
     private Set<Father> children = new HashSet<Father>(0);

     ....
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "Father")
public class Father {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Grandpa grandpa;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "father")
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<Child>(0);

    ....
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Father father;
}
```

when I delete grandpa, all his fathers and children get deleted as well, but when I delete father, his children stay in the database

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem...

when implementing deletion of Grandpa I used the session.delete(object)
when implementing deletion of Father I used pure sql...